# Which PHP function to use to read a binary file into a string?

Tags: php, file-io, binaryfiles

Which PHP function to use to read a binary file into a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$handle = @fopen("/path/to/file.bin", "rb");
if ($handle) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer[] = fgets($handle, 400);
    }
    fclose($handle);
    $buffer[0][0] = chr(hexdec("FF")); // set the first byte to 0xFF
}
// convert array to string
```

Comment: why to set first byte to 0xFF?

Comment: Under Windows, this code will treat files as plain text and will possibly corrupt the contents you read.

Comment: Thanks to Shakti Singh and Álvaro G. Vicario

Comment: You should call fopen() with 'rb', not 'r', so that it does reads as binary instead of text.

Answer (score 30):

[`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) is good enough. It seems that it read files in binary mode. I have made a little PHP script to check this. No MISMATCH messages was produced.

```
<?php

foreach (glob('/usr/bin/*') as $binary) {
    $php = md5(file_get_contents($binary));
    $shell = shell_exec("md5sum $binary");
    if ($php != preg_replace('/ .*/s', '', $shell)) {
        echo 'MISMATCH', PHP_EOL;
    }
    else {
        echo 'MATCH', PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo $php, '  ', $binary, PHP_EOL;
    echo $shell, PHP_EOL;
}
```

The following note is from [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

> Note: This function is binary-safe.

Comment: THis is the best answer. +1 for supplying a test. Well done.

Answer (score 19):

You are looking for [`fread`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) function.

> fread — Binary-safe file read

**Example:**

```
$filename = "c:\\files\\somepic.gif";
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
```

**Note:**

> On systems which differentiate between
>   binary and text files (i.e. Windows)
>   the file must be opened with 'b'
>   included in fopen() mode parameter.

Comment: The important bit here is the `b` flag in fopen().